# Nesting Multiple CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am building a layout represented in the following way.

[image]

The hierarchy is in the following way :

```
view
|
|__CollectionView (CV1), vertical scroll
         |__ CV1.SimpleCell1
         |__ CV1.SimpleCell ...
         |__ CV1.SimpleCell 9
         |
         |__CV1.Complex
                |
                |__ScrollView, horizontal scroll
                        |
                        |__CollectionView2 (CV2), horizontal scroll
                        |           |
                        |           |__n Titles
                        |
                        |__CollectionView3 (CV3), vertical scroll only
                                    |
                                    |__n images
```

There is a maincollection view with vertical scroll whose header is an image, and has couple of simple cells with normal visuals. After about 9 cell, I want a part in the view where the user is presented with another scrollable which can paginate or be free form horizontal scroll which has a title and a collecitonview (consisting of images) assigned to that title. Now the user should be able to scroll back and forth and still be scrolling vertically to access more images. Below is the representation of the same. 
I am really not able to figure out the correct possible implementation of the view here. Also, If I embedd a dynamic collectionview in the parent collectionview cell, i am not sure how the height will be dynamic.

[image]

The whole diagram of the architecture is  :

[image]

I really look forward to some guidance. I have been going crazy over this, any help is immensely appreciated.

Thanks. Please let me know for more info if any required.

Comment: Are `CollectionView2` and `CollectionView3` horizontal? And why you nested the `UIScrollView` in the collection view cell?

Comment: No everything is vertical. The uiscrollview nesting was just a try. But haven’t completely implemented. But have my doubts about it.

Comment: If everything is vertical you can do it using a single `UICollectionView`. It's almost always pointless having multiple nested collection view that scroll in the same direction

Comment: Plus the scrollview will facilitate the swiping across the scree. I ha ve 3 swiping views as depicted in picture. Each view has a header like one, two etc, and the it will contain the cells. Hence the collection view

Comment: It's hard to tell you without an actual example (like a gif or video that shows how all this stuff should behave)

Comment: The i need a tinder like feature that scrolls horizontally, one view each left and right. To which there will be photos. Hence another collection view

Comment: I get the part of not having multiple collection views. I Dont quite have the gif but have made marking to the image. Basically, I need a multiway swiping. Think like swiping images in gallery app. But instead of photo you have a whole collection virw. And each swipe you have a header named one, two etc. This whole thing has to be there after the cell 2 of collection view one.

Comment: Will really appreciate some pointers or any help

Comment: What should contain the `CollectionView2`? And why in your example you wrote `Cell1 - Cell9`? The `CollectionView3` should scroll with a kind of pagination (3 items) or a simple free scroll? And how the `CollectionView3` header should scroll?

Comment: Alright. So I have solved the collectview 2 issue. Infact. I just merged it to the first one. But coming to the question, the scrollview should be a free scroll and the header should have a parallax scroll with respect to its assigned collection view. The example is in this video. Seek to 24:35 - https://youtu.be/IUT0WByY7HI Instead of images I want collectionView and free scroll. And this will be in a cell or parent collection view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you said I would do something like this; could be not accurate, but this is the main idea.

```
view
|
|__CollectionView Vertical Scrolling or TableView
         |
         |__CV1.Simple Cell
         |__ …
         |__CV1.Simple Cell
         |
         |__CV1.Complex Cell
                |__CollectionView - Titles - Horizontal scroll (no interaction)
                |         |
                |         |__n Title Header Cell
                |
                |__CollectionView - Images - Horizontal scroll
                          |
                          |__n Image Cell
```

So the outer collection view is a simple collection view that has vertical scrolling and contains n cells;

- The `Complex Cell` is basically the cell that contain the horizontal stuff; no need to use a `UIScrollView` as we'll use two horizontal `UICollectionView`, one contains the headers ('One', 'Second'...) and one contains images; set horizontal scroll can be done in storyboard/xib or doing `collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.scrollDirection = .horizontal`
- `Complex Cell` is the `dataSource` and `delegate` of both collection views;
- `Title Collection View` must have `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` (users cannot scroll headers with the finger);
- The goal is to scroll the `Title Collection View` based on the `Image Collection View`; you could maybe use `scrollViewDidScroll` which is a method of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` (remember that `UICollectionViewDelegate` extends a `UIScrollViewDelegate`)

Other things to consider:

- The `Complex Cell` should have a fixed size (could be very complicated handle dynamic size in this case)
- You can maybe simplify by using a `UITableView` instead of a `UICollectionView` for the vertical scrolling, but this will not allow you to have grid layout for the `Simple Cell`

Comment: So Awesome of you to answer this. I do have couple of doubts though. The complex collectionview have n images scrolling vertically in the each title. They just shift the page right or left but then they continue to scroll vertically. The issue is, the images are indefinite, how can this ascertain the height of the collectionview in the complex cell and in the main collectionview aswell. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: Hey I have edited the question and the images. Please have a look at it. Meanwhile I am trying out your solution.